# Chef and Product versions- provisioning environments for different product versions

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am new to Chef and am currently getting my head around it. We are currently using Chef Solo in a Windows environment. We have product releases every 3 months. Chef is used in our organisation to setup production build environments, developer machines etc. The setup of these environments involves installing a bunch of developer tools such as Visual Studio, 3rd party software etc. This list of tools/software required to setup the environment can keep on changing across releases. For example: If product release 1.0 requires Visual Studio 2015 to be setup, product release 2.0 might require Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 and so on.

Just to be more precise, all servers should have identical software/configuration on them for a particular product release. We don't have the concept of staging and production. The build  environment we setup on a developer system should be identical to a build environment that we setup on a production box for a particular product release.

The way we make use of Chef is as follows:

- End user logs on to the server and launches a Powershell console with admin privileges.
- A Powershell script is executed. This script first installs chef solo on the client machine and copies all the chef scripts locally.
- The chef scripts are then executed to setup the developer build environment.

Here is my requirement: I did like to make use of chef to recreate the production build environment/developer build environment for a particular release.

For example: a developer would like to create the build environment for Product release 1.0. The chef scripts should handle this requirement. If the developer should like to create the developer environment for product release 2.0, the chef scripts should handle this as well.

Is this possible using Chef? I assume this is possible since Chef scripts can be versioned. If so, what is the way to achieve this using Chef?

One way I was thinking is that, we could label the chef scripts for every product version in our source control (Perforce). This way, whenever we want to set up the developer environment for a particular product version, we pull the associated scripts for that product version by making use of the label and setup the environment. However, this doesn't seem like a good enough approach.

Is there something similar to the labelling feature that all source control systems make available?  There should be something in Chef to do this.

Comment: Answers/guidance given on slack, don't cross post please.

Comment: Voting to close as opinion based as there's a bunch of way of achieving this.

Comment: @Tensibai i am just trying to get as many opinions as possible. I wouldn't go to the extent of assuming that every user on stack overflow is on slack. So few more answers here would be of great use. I request that this question be kept open unless there is a good enough reason to close this.

Comment: It is opinion based, everyone has its favorite workflow, it can't be answered by fact more than opinion and hence is out of topic for stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

If the requirements for different *product release versions* are more or less the same, you can handle that with 1 recipe, attributes and roles.

You create an attribute for your *product release versions* and do some logic in your recipe based on that.

Then you create roles, 1 for every *product release version*, and you add there the same attribute with the right value.

After that all you need, when configuring environment, is to pass the role to the chef-solo like:

```
chef-solo -o role[myrole]
```